# Output result is different while passing argument to thread methods

Tags: java, multithreading, static

So I am trying to pass arguments to my threads and my output is not as expected. Below is my code:

```
class BadThreadParam implements Runnable {
    static int c;

    public BadThreadParam( int a, int b ) {
        c = a + b;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println( c );
    }
}

public class BadThreadParamTest {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
       BadThreadParam shouldBe3 = new BadThreadParam( 1, 2 );
       BadThreadParam shouldBe5 = new BadThreadParam( 3, 12 );
       shouldBe3.run();  // Expect 3 but is 15.  WTF?
       shouldBe5.run();  // Expect 15.
    }
}
```

The final output I am expecting is:

```
3
15
```

but I am getting:

```
15
15
```

So is this a problem of thread interference? Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you change

```
static int c;
```

to

```
private int c;
```

Since you don't access the variable c out of your class, there is no reason it should be static. If you make it static, each time you change it, it will be that last value.

If you change it to private it's an 'instance' variable that is linked to the instance you create with new BadThreadParam(); so the output is the value that is given to that specific instance.

Answer (score 0):

`c` is a static variable.  This means that when one thread changes it, it changes for everyone.

You probably intend for it to be an instance variable.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Like how can I get the desired output?

Comment: I really don't know how I can really be any more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I just re-ordered the lines in your main method and here is the difference

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BadThreadParam shouldBe3 = new BadThreadParam(1, 2);
    shouldBe3.run();
    BadThreadParam shouldBe5 = new BadThreadParam(3, 12);
    shouldBe5.run(); 
}
```

And here is the output

```
3
15
```

Have a look at this along with the answers posted by [@JC97](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43576931/1651496) & [@Joe C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43576875/1651496)
Hope this will clear your doubts about the static variables

Answer (score 0):

You asked if the problem you're seeing is caused by thread interference. There is no possibility for thread interference in the posted program, because *there's only one thread*.

You're calling run on a Runnable, which executes it in the current thread.

If you want to create a new thread to execute each of your Runnables then you should change the code to

```
new Thread(shouldBe3).start();
new Thread(shouldBe15).start();
```

and then you will have a program with multiple threads. At that point there will be no guarantee that one thread will print its output before the other.

To confirm this you can add the line

```
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

to the body of each run method and to the main method. If they all print the same name then you aren't creating any threads.

As the other answers say, you're letting the second constructor call overwrite the contents of c set by the first constructor call. The static keyword means the variable belongs to the class, not to any one instance, and all instances access the same variable. c should be an instance variable (delete the static keyword) so that each Runnable object has its own copy.